multiple springboot microservices with single connection pool
I have multiple microservices springboot app running as jar file, each of them will create a connection to a centralize oracle database. I wish to have a connection pool for all these microservices to share use.
Currently I am thinking to change all these springboot app to build into war file and deploy as Web application in Payara, and configure connection pool on payara for all the microservices.
So far it is working in my testing.
Would like to know if there is any other designs and what are their pros and cons?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your system design did not make sense. You must remove this system design.

the purpose for this design is due to we have a centralize DB therefore we need a common connection pool to control the load. as for springboot microservices is for better modularity and readability.
@VyDo May I know why it does not make sense and must be removed?
